# How to use different EntityGraph as annotation on findAll and findOne repository methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring project which uses Hibernate to interact with an underlying MySQL db. Please note EHCACHE is used as Hibernate second level cache.

I am trying to load different dependent objects by using different @EntityGraph annotations on findAll and fineOne method. I first load the entity using findAll method and then load the same object using findOne method - to my surprise it simply neglects the @EntityGraph specified on findOne method and instead returns data using the EntityGraph specified on findAll.

To explain the problem better I am copying the entity class and repository class below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName="course")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "categories", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("categories")),
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "batches", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("batches"))
})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")

public class Course implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Batch> batches = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "COURSE_CATEGORY",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="courses_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="categorys_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

The repository class is:

```
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course,Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "categories", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Page<Course> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @EntityGraph(value = "batches", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Course findByIdAndPublished(Long id);

}
```

And after load up the calls happen in this format:

- courseRepository.findAll() => This loads and returns all Course objects with categories loaded
- courseRepository.findOne(1) => This returns Course with id 1 but again categories are loaded and not batches (Please note as per the EntityGraph I was expecting batches to be loaded and not categories)

Thanks in advance for helping out,
Ankit